# Get user input in Webapp and display some rows in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with ticket number, call date,  customer mobile no, customer name
I want to take the user input (Ticket number) in a Webapp.
From that, I will find the customer mobile number in the table.
From the customer mobile number, I want to display all the matching rows (in the same table) to the user in HTML. I want to display all the calls made by the customer (he could have made many calls before)

I referred to

[How to search and filter a Google Sheet based on two parameters in two different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441131/how-to-search-and-filter-a-google-sheet-based-on-two-parameters-in-two-different)

and Tried

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}
//
function getValuesFromSS(search) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zObr0he1SYJkOXMMyFrOWk-0OtV6w/edit#gid=926906658")//service calls
  var calsht=ss.getSheetByName('Calls');
  //var lastRow = calsht.getLastRow();
  var arange = calsht.getRange("A:D").getValues(); 
  for (m= arange.length-1; m>0; m--){
    if (arange[m][0]==search.name){//search.name
      var cusmob=arange[m][3];
      //Logger.log(m);      
      //Logger.log(cusmob);
    }
  }
  var names = '';
  var techs = '';
  var eqips = '';
  var urls = '';
  var lastCol = calsht.getLastColumn();
  for (m= arange.length-1; m>0; m--){
    if (arange[m][3]==cusmob){
      var values = calsht.getRange("A"+(m+1)+":AL"+(m+1)).getValues(); //get all values for the row
      var name = values[0][4]; //column E
      var tech = values[0][5];  //column F
      var eqip = values[0][14];  //column O
      var url = values[0][37]; // AL
      //Logger.log(url);      
      names+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + name + "</td>");
      techs+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + tech + "</td>");
      eqips+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + eqip + "</td>");
      urls+=Utilities.formatString('<td>' + '<a href="' + url + '">Inv</a>' + '</td>');
    }//if
  }//for
  return {
  first: names,
  second: techs,
  third: eqips,
  fourth: urls
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

function setPageValues () {
  var search = document.getElementsByName('searchtext')[0].value;
  var obj = {};
  if (!search) alert("Ticket No is required");
  if (search) {
    obj.name = search;
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(disp).getValuesFromSS(obj);
}

    function disp(values){
      document.getElementById("results1").innerHTML = values.first;
      document.getElementById("results2").innerHTML = values.second;
      document.getElementById("results3").innerHTML = values.third;
      document.getElementById("results4").innerHTML = values.fourth;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
tr { 
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  }
td {
    border: 1px solid Black;
    display: block; 
    }
</style>
<body>

<input type="text" name="searchtext">
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="setPageValues();">

<br>
<div name="resultbox">
<table>
<tr id="results1">
</tr>
<tr id="results2">
</tr>
<tr id="results3">
</tr>
<tr id="results4">
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Now it seems to be working.

I changed from findall to for loop.

Comment: At what point do you want to send data, to what function do you want to pass it, and what is the data you wish to pass?

Comment: I want to take user input (Ticket number). Then I will find the customer mobile number corresponding to that ticket number. Then I will filter the sheet for the mobile number. Then I want to display the filtered rows on the screen for the user to view

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

> you can display your results with the withSuccessHandler